# Setting callback function in array_map giving error

Tags: php, callback

```
class Test
{
    public $callback = "sqrt";

    public function cube($n)
    {
        return($n * $n * $n);
    }   

    public function cool()
    {
        $a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        $b = array_map( $this->callback , $a);
        var_dump($b);
    }   
}

$t = new Test();
$t->cool();
```

In this code if $**callback** is set to something like **intval** or **sqrt** then it will work fine , but when i try to use **cube** method as callback function it is giving following error. Why so
and how to call method **cube** from **cool** method as callback

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$b = array_map( array($this, $this->callback) , $a);
```

Output is:

```
array
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 8
  2 => int 27
  3 => int 64
  4 => int 125
```

If its a static method:

```
$b = array_map( "Test::staticMethodName" , $a);
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, the problem is, when you giving this parameter to your `array_map`, it parse, what's in the property of your class called `callback`. There is a string value: `cube`. You have no global `cube` function. `intval` and `sqrt` are global functions, so they will work. So you need to pass as the PHP documents says: `A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.`

This is why my example works, because you have an instantiated method `$this`, and the method name in `$this->callback`.

And for static methods:

`Static class methods can also be passed without instantiating an object of that class by passing the class name instead of an object at index 0. As of PHP 5.2.3, it is also possible to pass 'ClassName::methodName'.`

Comment: Yes it works but i still don't understand what is going on. Will u please shed some light on the same

Comment: See my edited code, i tried to explain. Tell me if it's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can use an array to associate an object and a method call as a callable

```
array_map(array($this, $this->callback), $array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$b = array_map(array($this, 'cube'), $a);
```

instead of

```
$b = array_map( $this->callback , $a);
```