# Change one PHP array to another

Tags: php, arrays

I am receiving this from a query:

```
[ 0 => [ 'lat' => '-33.84120341953682' 'lon' => '151.21485817982244' ] 1 => [ 'lat' => '-33.841392251850664' 'lon' => '151.21484300641407' ] 2 => [ 'lat' => '-33.8415660681554' 'lon' => '151.21480011389457' ] 3 => [ 'lat' => '-33.84172686021847' 'lon' => '151.2147391354549' ] 4 => [ 'lat' => '-33.84192892420166' 'lon' => '151.21462289682538' ] 5 => [ 'lat' => '-33.84210993164981' 'lon' => '151.2144873482388' ] 6 => [ 'lat' => '-33.84227488089544' 'lon' => '151.21434574122455' ] 7 => [ 'lat' => '-33.84239061806536' 'lon' => '151.21420521442346' ] ]
```

How do use the result of the query to put them to use as below?

```
$coords = [
        new LatLng(['lat' => -33.8368934679516, 'lng' => 151.211801678416]),
        new LatLng(['lat' => -33.8366464651179, 'lng' => 151.211847264952]),
    ];
```

I have tried a messy concatenate and was hoping a PHP expert to shine a light on this one.

Comment: This also looks related/relvant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26716049/2943403

Answer (score 1):

```
$newCoordsArray = array_map(function($value) {
   return new LatLng(['lat' => $value['lon'], 'lng' => $value['lon']]);
}, $coords);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.